# Modify line entity with entmod

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

```
(defun C:incercare (/ )
 (setq linie (entget (entlast))
       startp (assoc 10 linie) ; line start point
       lineen (subst (list 10 5.0 5.0 0.0) startp linie))

(entmod linie)
  )
```

I am trying to modify the starting point of the last line drawed.After calling the incercare function nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by user CAD Developer, you are calling `entmod` on the *original* DXF data list assigned to the `linie` variable, and not the *modified* list returned by the `subst` function and assigned to the `lineen` variable.

However, note that your code can be condensed considerably, as each step needn't be assigned to a separate variable, e.g.:

```
(defun c:incercare ( / linie )
    (setq linie (entget (entlast)))
    (entmod (subst '(10 5.0 5.0 0.0) (assoc 10 linie) linie))
)
```

A few points to note here:

- Notice that I have declared the symbol `linie` as a local variable within the `defun` expression, so that the scope of this variable is limited to the `c:incercare` function and doesn't remain global.
- I have quoted the new coordinate as a literal list using the single quote or apostrophe - this is possible because the list contains only literal data (constant numerical values), and no variable data - I discuss this difference in more detail in my tutorial on [The Apostrophe and the Quote Function](http://lee-mac.com/quote.html).

Your current function is assuming that the last entity added to the drawing database is a `LINE` entity (or at least, an entity whose geometry is defined by DXF group 10). As such, you may want to include a conditional expression to test whether or not this is the case and branch accordingly, e.g.:

```
(defun c:incercare ( / ent enx )
    (if
        (and
            (setq ent (entlast))
            (setq enx (entget ent))
            (= "LINE" (cdr (assoc 0 enx)))
        )
        (entmod (subst '(10 5.0 5.0 0.0) (assoc 10 enx) enx))
        (princ "\nThe last entity was not a line.")
    )
    (princ)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
(entmod linie)
```

to

```
(entmod lineen)
```